# how to display searched json records one by one through next and previous buttons?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, json

I have a working code which searches the json records and displays all the records one by one. I want to display the records based on the search term,

The working code is following:

```
    <!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>jQuery PHP Json Response</title>
<style type="text/css">
div
{
text-align:center;
padding:10px;
}

#msg {
width: 500px;
margin: 0px auto;
}
.members {
width: 500px ;
background-color: beige;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<input type="text" id="search-json-input" />
<input type="button" id="search-json-submit" value="search" />
<br/>
<br/>

<input type="button" name="next" id="next" value="NEXT" />
<br/>
<input type="button" name="previous" id="previous" value="PREV" />
<br/>
<div id="msg">
    <table id="userdata" border="1">
        <thead>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Sex</th>
            <th>Location</th>
            <th>Picture</th>
            <th>audio</th>
            <th>video</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody></tbody>
    </table>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">

var users = [];
var idx = 0;
var renderRow = function (idx) {
    if (idx < 0) idx = 0;
    if (idx > (users.length - 1)) idx = (users.length - 1);
    var user = users[idx];
    var tblRow = "<tr>" + "<td>" + user.email + "</td>" + "<td>" + user.sex + "</td>" + "<td>" + user.location + "</td>" + "<td>" + "<img src=" + user.image + ">" + "</td>" + "<td>" + "<audio src=" + user.video + " controls>" + "</td>" + "<td>" + "<video src=" + user.video + " controls>" + "</td>" + "</tr>";
    $('#userdata tbody').html(tblRow);
};
var url = "json.php";
$.getJSON(url, function (data) {
    users = data.members;
    renderRow(idx);
    $('#next').click(function() {
        idx++;
        renderRow(idx);
    });
    $('#previous').click(function() {
        idx--;
        renderRow(idx);
    });
});

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The result of json.php can be seen here: http://sco7.com/components/phonegap/json.php

Answer (score 0):

- Attach the JSON response as a variable to something, so it can be referenced later.

  - Warning if you have >1000 items this approach doesn't work very well, as its too slow to return larger datasets.
- Create a current index variable (an int).
- Remove the loop in the response handler (i.e. the call to each() )
- Update your document to have a "left button", and "right button" and the 0th item

  - The buttons must not submit anything to a server.
  - The appended item may have the same formatting as what you have at present
- The created buttons have an onclick handler that:

  - Repeat until valid changed index

    - For left, confirms if the index is valid if decremented, then decrements it.
    - For right, confirms if the index is valid if incremented, then increments it.
    - Does your data validation (the regex) as current.
    - If incorrect data change the index again.
  - Deletes the current displayed item text, and appends the item at the updated index.

Comment: Can you explain it with example.

Comment: Can i write that? yes but not quickly (too many things going on). check here on Weds or so